# How to divide 1d array which contains dates to several smaller arrays (2d array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array contains dates (yyyy/mm/dd format):

> ["2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-09", "2019-02-10", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-06", "2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-12-05", "2019-12-06"]

I want to divide it to several smaller pieces. I want to get 2d array and each array inside 2d array should has dates without gaps. So if the difference between two dates is more than 1 I want to add next date to next array inside 2d array. I don't know how many 1d arrays I will need, it depends on input array.
I expect to return sth like this:

> [
>
> ["2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-09", "2019-02-10"],
>
> ["2019-07-05", "2019-07-06", "2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
>
> ["2019-12-05", "2019-12-06"]
>
> ];

This is what I did already but it isn't work properly:

```
    function divideIntoBlocks(variant){
        var array = [],
            start = new Date(variant[0]),
            stop = new Date(variant[variant.length - 1]);
        for(var i = start; i <= stop; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)){

            if(start == new Date(variant[0])){
                var newArray = [];
                newArray.push(start);
            }
            else{
                if(getDiffDays(start.getDate() - 1, start) == 1){
                    newArray.push(start);
                }
                else{
                    array.push(newArray);
                    newArray = [];
                    newArray.push(start)
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(array);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that your array is already sorted before using the solution below.

#### Solution with numbers as an input:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13];
const result = [];

if (arr.length > 0) {
  result.push([arr[0]]);

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] > 1) {
      result.push([arr[i]]);
    } else {
      result[result.length - 1].push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result); // [ [ 1 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ], [ 10, 11 ], [ 13 ] ]
```

#### Solution with dates as an input:

```js
const arr = [
  "2019-02-05",
  "2019-02-06",
  "2019-02-07",
  "2019-02-08",
  "2019-02-09",
  "2019-02-10",
  "2019-07-05",
  "2019-07-06",
  "2019-07-07",
  "2019-07-08",
  "2019-07-09",
  "2019-07-10",
  "2019-12-05",
  "2019-12-06"
];

const result = [];

if (arr.length > 0) {
  result.push([arr[0]]);

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (diffDays(arr[i], arr[i - 1]) > 1) {
      result.push([arr[i]]);
    } else {
      result[result.length - 1].push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);

function diffDays(dateStr1, dateStr2) {
  const date1 = new Date(dateStr1);
  const date2 = new Date(dateStr2);
  const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return diffDays;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the *diffDays* functions works because the dates are parsed as UTC, avoiding daylight saving transitions. It could be more concise: `return (new Date(dateStr2) - new Date(dateStr1)) / 8.64e7`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could group your dates based on the month, reduce the array to object of object, get values of the object as array and sort:

```js
let groupKey = 0;
let a = ["2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-09", "2019-02-10", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-06", "2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-12-05", "2019-12-06"]
let finalArr = Object.values(a.reduce((r, o) => {
  let m = o.split(('-'))[1];
  (r[m]) ? r[m].data.push(o): r[m] = {
    group: String(m),
    data: [o]
  };
  return r;
}, {})).sort((l, t) => l.group > t.group ? 1 : -1).map(u => u.data.sort((l, t) => new Date(l) > new Date(t) ? 1 : -1));
console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Making akobbs answer work with dates:

```
function nextdate (a) {
    const r = [];
    if (a.length > 0) {
      r.push([a[0]]);
      for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(new Date(a[i]) - new Date(a[i - 1])) / 864e+5 > 1) r.push([a[i]]);
        else r[r.length - 1].push(a[i]);
      }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```js
//step 0 init
const DAY = 86400000;

//step 1 - fetch 
let arrDates = ["2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-09", "2019-02-10", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-06", "2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-12-05", "2019-12-06", "IDIOT DATE"];

//setp 2 - map to date objects
arrDates = arrDates.map((item) => {
  return new Date(item);
});

//step 3 - filter for not wanted results
arrDates = arrDates.filter(e => e instanceof Date && !isNaN(e));

//step 4 sort
arrDates = arrDates.sort((a, b) => {
  return a - b
});

//step 5 reducing it to 3d array

arrDates = arrDates.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    //defines previousResult by looking up the accumulator

    let previousResult = acc[acc.length - 1][acc[acc.length - 1].length - 1]

    //check if dates difference exactly 86400000 Milliseconds AKA DAY
    if (cur.getTime() - previousResult.getTime() === DAY) {
      //true :: push to latest array in the accumulator
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur)
    } else {
      //false push new array with value to the accumulator
      acc.push([cur])
    }
    //returns accumulator back so it can be used every time
    return acc;
  },
  //initial value Array.reduce( callback.fn , initial value  )
  // we take out the first value and init the stuff
  [
    [arrDates.shift()]
  ]);

console.log(arrDates);
```